# MS Access - Form fields do not appear in split database

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I am having trouble deploying an access database into a multi-user environment.

I have split the database into front end and back end files. The back end file is on a shared network and the front end has been saved locally on the user's computer. I have checked that the tables are linked correctly and have had no problems opening the tables or viewing reports while using the front end file so I know the data is linked correctly.

**My problem comes when I go to enter new information into a form while using the front end file of the split database**. This form is intended for data entry only.

My form properties are currently set to:

- Data Entry - Yes
- Allow Additions - Yes
- Allow Deletions - Yes
- Allow Edits - Yes
- Allow Filters - Yes
- Record Locks - No Locks

When I open the form in form view, the form fields and command buttons do not appear, only the header of the form. However, everything does then appear when I switch to design view. When I changed the form property to “data entry – no”, the fields then appeared but I could only view existing entries and could not add any new entries.

I have not specified a specific "Date Mode" within my "open form macro" from my switchboard as I read it overrides the form properties and I am not sure where my error lies.

My client settings for my database are currently set to:

- Default open mode - Shared
- Default record locking - Edited record
- Encryption method - Legacy encryption

This is my first time building a database so this is all still a learning curve for me and any advice is greatly, greatly appreciated!!

Thank you so much.

Comment: It sounds like your form might be based on a read-only query.  This link: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html lists reasons why your query might be read-only.

Comment: Is the shared network local, or remote?